# Windows 7 Enterprise: stopping hibernation?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

Is it possible to stop Win7 Enterprise from ever going into hibernation?

My laptop takes a long time to resume into desktop, and I very rarely I let the battery level to drop to below 30%, so hibernation isn't really helping.

Comment: Possible dupticate of http://superuser.com/questions/347927/how-to-really-turn-off-hibernation-in-win7.

Comment: ^ He just wants to disable hibernation, not delete the hiberfile.sys and stuff

Answer (score 2):

It is described here

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/819-hibernate-enable-disable.html

TL;DR To disable Hibernate, open an elevated command prompt, type `powercfg -h off` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: So in this case if the laptop's asleep and the battery runs low, it will not hibernate and instead shut down improperly?

Comment: still hibernates overnight with a 80% full battery.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your power plan to go to standby when closing the laptop's lid, in *Control Panel » Power Options*.

Comment: It is sleep by default but Windows automatically hibernates after a certain period of time